# image output failed in pdf xhtml2pdf

Tags: django, xhtml2pdf

I have my views set up like following:

views.py

```
class PDFTemplateView(TemplateView):
    Model = TemplateInfo
    template_name = 'hello.html'


    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = self.Model.objects.get(id = kwargs['pk'])

        html  = get_template(self.template_name).render(Context({'object' : obj}))

        result = StringIO.StringIO()
        rendering = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)

        if not rendering.err:
            return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), mimetype='application/pdf')
        return HttpResponse('We had some errors<pre>%s</pre>' % escape(html))
```

I found a solution in this very feed with the defination of `fetch_resource()` function but that didnt helped me. I read the documentation and I was better off without the function.

this is my template "hello.html"

```
<style type="text/css">

@page {
    background-image: url('/media/image/mainbg.jpg'); #this wouldnot give image too
    size: letter portrait;

    @frame header_frame {           /* Static Frame */
        -pdf-frame-content: header_content;
        left: 50pt; width: 512pt; top: 50pt; height: 40pt;
        -pdf-frame-border: 1;    /* for debugging the layout */
    }
    @frame content_frame {          /* Content Frame */
        left: 50pt; width: 512pt; top: 90pt; height: 632pt;
        -pdf-frame-border: 1;    /* for debugging the layout */
    }
    @frame footer_frame {           /* Another static Frame */
        -pdf-frame-content: footer_content;
        left: 50pt; width: 512pt; top: 772pt; height: 20pt;
        -pdf-frame-border: 1;    /* for debugging the layout */
    }

 </style>
 </head>
<div id="header_content">Lyrics-R-Us</div>

<div id="footer_content">(c) - page <pdf:pagenumber>
    of <pdf:pagecount>
</div>

<ul>
    <li>{{ object.emp_name }}</li>
    <li>{{ object.designation }}</li>
    <li>{{ object.image.url }}</li>
</ul>
```

Everything seems fine till now. But I cannot get the image in the pdf. this `{{ object.image.url}}` gives me a fie path string in the pdf but not the image. Am i missing something. Help me please. I am stuck for like hours already.

Comment: I figured out that myself. I was in such a rush, i thought i would just copy and paste the code sinppet. Sorry for troubling you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xhtmltopdf does not use "real" css rules. Your background image must be in pdf format. Try to convert '/media/image/mainbg.jpg' to pdf and use `background-image: url('/media/image/mainbg.pdf')`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. But that didnt do anything. Im still stuck!

Comment: I remember I struggled with this question too... Try `background-image: url(/media/image/mainbg.pdf)` without quotes.

Comment: I did that already with and without quotes. Do you remember anything how you got over with this ??

Comment: My template (doc.html) code is `@page {
  background-image: url({{ bgpdf }});
  size: ... }` which I call with render and the argument `{'bgpdf':'path/to/doc.pdf'}`. I would do two things: try first to render the view in html format to ensure the path to the document is right and second try to refer to a native pdf file to ensure the format is right. I also commented the link_callback=fetch_resource in my code.

Comment: thanks man, for your answer. Let me try that and ill get back to you

Comment: hey, i got stuck with other stuffs. YOur answer helped me quite a bit. One other thing, how do i display a table with background-image??

Comment: Or how do i configure the height and width of the background image?? I would want to manipulate the image as of my wish.

Comment: You have a very well illustrated example here https://gist.github.com/elbaschid/8776935, which works ... in theory. I never tried to create a table with background however.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that xhtml2pdf cannot find these images unless you define a link_callback function that defines the path to your static and media files.

This function is in the xhtml2pdf docs:

```
def link_callback(uri, rel):
    # use short variable names
    sUrl = settings.STATIC_URL      # Typically /static/
    sRoot = settings.STATIC_ROOT    # Typically /home/userX/project_static/
    mUrl = settings.MEDIA_URL       # Typically /static/media/
    mRoot = settings.MEDIA_ROOT     # Typically /home/userX/project_static/media/

    # convert URIs to absolute system paths
    if uri.startswith(mUrl):
        path = os.path.join(mRoot, uri.replace(mUrl, ""))
    elif uri.startswith(sUrl):
        path = os.path.join(sRoot, uri.replace(sUrl, ""))

    # make sure that file exists
    if not os.path.isfile(path):
        raise Exception('media URI must start with %s or %s' % (sUrl, mUrl))
    return path
```

Make sure to define all of the paths in the link_callback function (STATIC_URL...etc). Then when you render the document, include the link_callback like this:

```
rendering = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result, link_callback=link_callback)
```

Comment: im getting this error `global name link_callback is not defined` in this line `rendering = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result, link_callback=link_callback)`. I have defined the function link_callback exactly like you said.

Comment: Is the link_callback inside the PDFTemplateView class so that get can access that function?

Comment: Yes that is inside the class. I followed the documentation yet i was receiving that error. I found a solution that worked for me and that was removing the `link_callback()` function from the class and defining the hard coded media urls. But Im still wondering what caused that error. I followed every instructions from the documentation.

Comment: link_callback is a function that tells xhtml2pdf where to find your static and media files (as long as urls are correct in settings.py). Just be aware that the module docs have errors, but I tried the solution I posted and got it working no problem.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. please check your STATIC_ROOT in settings as it should point to the location of where you have stored your static files.

django-easy-pdf could not locate your assets (images, css, etc) until you point them to the STATIC_ROOT.

https://github.com/nigma/django-easy-pdf/blob/master/docs/usage.rst

Answer (score 1):

i've been struggling a long time with a similar problem until I removed :

```
<pdf:pagecount>
```

Give it a try

Answer (score -1):

Late answer but none of the above solved it for me.

Here's what solved the issue for me:

Define STATIC_ROOT in settings.py as:

```
os.path.abspath('collected-static/')
```

Another gotcha is that the way the link_callback function is written, you have to have MEDIA_URL defined since the default value for MEDIA_URL is "" which matches the start of every URI.

Either define MEDIA_URL or re-write the link_callback function to check for static links first:

```
def link_callback(uri, rel):
    # use short variable names
    sUrl = settings.STATIC_URL      # Typically /static/
    sRoot = settings.STATIC_ROOT    # Typically /home/userX/project_static/
    mUrl = settings.MEDIA_URL       # Typically "" if not defined in settings.py
    mRoot = settings.MEDIA_ROOT     # Typically /home/userX/project_static/media/

    # convert URIs to absolute system paths
    if uri.startswith(sUrl):
        # Replaces 'static/image.png' with 'c:\\my-project\\collected-static/image.png'
        path = os.path.join(sRoot, uri.replace(sUrl, ""))
    elif uri.startswith(mUrl):
        # MEDIA_URL default value is "" so everything matches this
        path = os.path.join(mRoot, uri.replace(mUrl, ""))

    # make sure that file exists
    if not os.path.isfile(path):
        raise Exception('media URI must start with %s or %s' % (sUrl, mUrl))
    return path
```